# Pesky leak in setter/getter methods

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

It seems like I keep asking the same questions, memory related. My current code works exactly as I intend it, but I cannot figure why I am showing a leak here in Instruments.

```
-(NSDate *)startTimeAndDate {
    NSDate *dateToReturn = nil;
    if (startTimeAndDate != nil) {
        dateToReturn = [startTimeAndDate retain];
    } else { //is currently nil, this will be the initial setting
        //return default time if we have a working date
        if (finishTimeAndDate != nil) {
            dateToReturn = [[self dateFromDate:finishTimeAndDate withNewTime:defaultStartTime]retain];
        } else {
            //return the default time with today's date if we have nothing set as yet
            dateToReturn = [[self dateFromDate:[NSDate date] withNewTime:defaultStartTime] retain];
        }
        //save the initial setting
        self.initialStartDateAndTime = [[dateToReturn copy] autorelease];
    }
    [startTimeAndDate release];
    startTimeAndDate = dateToReturn;
    return startTimeAndDate;
}


-(void)setStartTimeAndDate:(NSDate *)inStartTimeAndDate {

    BOOL initialAssignment = NO;
    if (startTimeAndDate == nil) {
        initialAssignment = YES;
    }

    if (startTimeAndDate != inStartTimeAndDate) { //skip everything if passed object is same as current
        //check that the start time is prior to finish only if finish time has been entered
        NSDate *dateToSetStartTo = nil;
        if (finishTimeAndDate != nil) {
            if ([inStartTimeAndDate earlierDate:finishTimeAndDate] == inStartTimeAndDate) {
                // use the new time, it is earlier than current finish time
                dateToSetStartTo = [inStartTimeAndDate retain];
            } else { //start time is not earlier then finish time
                // the received entry is invalid, set start time to 1 default interval from finish
                dateToSetStartTo = [[finishTimeAndDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-self.defaultTimeInterval] retain];
            }
        } else { //finish time is nil
            // use the new time without testing, nothing else is set
            dateToSetStartTo = [inStartTimeAndDate retain];
        }
        [startTimeAndDate release];
        startTimeAndDate = dateToSetStartTo;
    }
    if (initialAssignment) {
        self.initialStartDateAndTime = [[self.startTimeAndDate copy] autorelease];
    }
}
```

So far as I can see, I am balancing all retains with `release` or `autorelease`. The leak appears to be caused on the first pass only. I have a view controller, it creates my model (wherein this code lies) and sets a start date, nothing else is done at that point. If I close that view controller at that point, Instruments shows that I am leaving the date object as a leak.

I placed a `NSLog` to show retain count at `dealloc` and, sure enough, it has retain count of 2 before my final release is called, leaving a retain count of 1 when it should have been destroyed. It is always the same regardless if I close immediately after initialization or set and get a hundred times. `retainCount` is 2 prior to my final call to `release` in `dealloc`.

I have been looking at this all weekend and cannot figure where I've gone wrong.

To clarify, the initial call is to set the `startTimeAndDate` property. At that point all other fields are nil or 0 if not objects. That `startTimeAndDate` object appears to be the leaking object.

Comment: Please indent your code correctly and tell us where the leak is indicated.

Comment: I apologize if it is not clear. I have only posted a couple of times so far and the format is new to me. It looks to be indented correctly as far as I can tell in my browser. The leak is the NSDate object "startTimeAndDate" I believe.

Comment: Thanks, much better now. The code blocks here are funny about tabs for some reason -- it works better to use spaces when posting.

Comment: You have unusually many retain's in your code. The copy/autorelease stuff looks wrong. In your .h file you can specify that a property should retain, which will eliminate most of this code shown here. Best of luck.

Comment: I do have the property set to retain, however being as I am overriding both getter and setter, I expect I have to return or create a retained object from there. I have tried it without them and I do wind up with exception, call to dealloc'd object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dam, ignore what I said. I just went through the code again and you're right. I think you are basically being burned by the complexity of the code. I found it quite difficult to follow, especially with the number of properties. I think what I would do at this stage is to copy the code to a unit test and run it from there. Then you can better test and debug it. I would recommend [GHUnit](http://gabriel.github.com/gh-unit/) if you do not already have unit testing in place.

The other thing that occurs to be is that there is code executing somewhere else in your program that is retaining the date. Therefore triggering the leak. For example if `inStartTimeAndDate` is coming in with a retain count of 1, but is not released by the code that called the setter then you could end up with `startTimeAndDate` with a retain of 2.

Having said that, here's my rewrite of the getter in an attempt to clarify whats going on:

```
-(NSDate *)startTimeAndDate {

    // If we have it, bail out fast.
    if (startTimeAndDate == nil) {
        return startTimeAndDate;
    }

    // Is currently nil, this will be the initial setting
    NSDate *dateToReturn = nil;
    //return default time if we have a working date
    if (finishTimeAndDate != nil) {
        dateToReturn = [self dateFromDate:finishTimeAndDate withNewTime:defaultStartTime];
    } else {
        //return the default time with today's date if we have nothing set as yet
        dateToReturn = [self dateFromDate:[NSDate date] withNewTime:defaultStartTime];
    }
    //save the initial setting
    self.initialStartDateAndTime = [[dateToReturn copy] autorelease];

    startTimeAndDate = [dateToReturn retain];
    return startTimeAndDate;
}
```

The main reason for this re-write was that it appeared that if there was a `startTimeAndDate` then the code was doing this:

```
dateToReturn = [startTimeAndDate retain];
...
[startTimeAndDate release];
startTimeAndDate = dateToReturn;
```

Which seemed a little pointless because it's effective doing a retain, release and self assignment. It would work, but there's less chance of a bug if we leave it out.

Comment: Honestly, I think this might be close to how it started. The methods got more and more convoluted the more I tried to understand where the leak was coming from. I had tabled it for a while, come back for a fresh look now that you've given me some things to consider. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 4):

Firstly, can you describe the problem you are trying to solve with this code? I ask because it appears very complex and my initial thought is that simplification will not only clarify what you are doing, but is also likely to solve your leak as well.

Secondly, (and I may have this wrong), you only need to retain/release objects if you expect those objects to exist beyond the scope of the method, or you expect that they may be released by some code that you are claling in you method. Based on this, you appear to be over retaining and releasing in your code. I think you can remove a lot of it.

Again I may be wrong, but it appears that you will indeed leak. The reason I think so is this - on your first pass you retain some data in `dateToReturn` which is a local variable. Then you do

```
self.initialStartDateAndTime = [[dateToReturn copy] autorelease];
```

But this is not releasing `dateToReturn`. Instead it is releasing the copy of `dateToReturn`. `dateToReturn` is still retained. Presuming that you intend to autorelease the copy because `initialStartDateAndTime` is set with retain, I think you should be doing:

```
self.initialStartDateAndTime = [[dateToReturn copy] autorelease];
[dateToReturn release];
```

Of course, if you remove the extra retain/release's then this becomes simpler again.

The final thing I would suggest is around naming. The problem with code like this is that you have a number of methods and variables, all with very similar names. This can make it difficult to follow and lead to bugs. So ask yourself if you really need this many variables. And can you make your code more readible by changing some of the names.

Comment: startTimeAndDate is a retained property. I am overriding the setter and getter in order to validate and provide defaults. The validation rules and default values change based on the state of some of the other properties, like whether or not a finish time has been entered, if it is a new record or editing etc. initialStartTimeAndDate is another retained property with standard setter and getter from @synthesize. It is meant to be altogether separate from dateToReturn/startTimeAndDate, hence the copy.

Comment: I would not want to release dateToReturn as that is ultimately what I set startTimeAndDate to retained as the new object in that property.

Comment: You will need to release it at least after setting startTimeAndDate, otherwise it's a leak and breaks the memory management rules.

Comment: Is that correct? In my setter, I am setting it retained. That retain is balanced by release in the dealloc method is what I am assuming. I would agree if I was using standard setter, but I am overriding and setting the ivar myself.